# Algorithm for perfect non-binary graph layout

Tags: java, algorithms, graph

I have a complex non-binary graph model.
Each tree node can have multiple children&parents (a node can also have a connection to it's "brother").

A node is represented as square on screen with lines to the connected nodes.
For that I want to use Draw2D and GEF libraries.

The problem I am facing is the graph layout.

I need a nice algorithm that can reposition the square nodes and the connections with minimum intersections and also make it symmetric as possible.

Comment: If a node has multiple parents, it is not a tree.

Comment: Have you looked into GraphViz? http://www.graphviz.org/

Comment: @ftr yes, it's graph.

Comment: JUNG is a graph visualization framework for Java, but I don't know how well it fits into your technology stack. http://jung.sourceforge.net/

Comment: If there are parents, children and siblings, must the siblings be aligned along an axis?  Are there any restrictions at all visually? Aside from minimum intersections?  Is distance between connections a factor?

Comment: It sounds like you have a directed graph.

Answer (score 4):

Your parent-child relation probably creates a partial order.  Google "partial order graph layout" and top hits mention things like "Coffman–Graham algorithm" and "Hasse diagrams."  Maybe some research in those directions would be productive.